# Extract the contact form 7 data and send as an attachment through cron job

Tags: wordpress, cron, contact-form-7

I have multiple contact forms and I am using `contact form 7` and I am using [Advanced CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cf7-db/) to extract the CSV reports. 
I want to write the cron job using `WP-Cron` or any other plugin to extract the CSV reports weekly and email the sheets to given email address. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this by mapping my form submission to a custom post using [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/) plugin. This allows you to use WordPress core functions to retrieve your post and field data.

I would then use the answer to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160511/export-to-csv-wordpress) to build the CSV file programmatically.  Note that in the linked answer, the code is setting up '[Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)' of the header output stream so as to trigger the file save event on the browser, however you need yours to be attached to your mail, which can be done by appending it as part of the email body.  Check this [tutorial](http://carlofontanos.com/generate-csv-file-and-send-as-email-attachment-php/) to see how to do that.